# JQuery .css setTimeout negates my forms for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am using an if statement to trigger a css repositioning based on where my menubar is located.

```
if($("#menu").hasClass("topmenu")==true)
{

setTimeout(function() {$(".centeringContainer").css(
    {
    "position":"absolute",
    "text-align": "center",
    "padding-top": "60px",
    "width":"100%",
    "z-index": "-5",
    "padding-left":"20px",
    "margin-left":"20px"
    })}, 1); 



}
```

I don't know why, but something about this setTimeout doesn't allow the user to fill out forms on the page. Any text boxes that I need to fill out just get stuck, there isn't even a cursor. Maybe the timeout is stopping all other interactions or something? Any suggestions?

Comment: Running a `setTimeout` every millisecond takes a bit of power... There're better ways to check where the menubar is located and react.

Comment: He's using `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`. This will just wait 1 millisecond, then update the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing your markup, but I think the `centeringContainer` is overlaying all your other form elements. You have it absolutely positioned with 100% width, so this could be on top of your inputs, making them appear "stuck".

Set the width of the `centeringContainer` to `1px` and see if that fixes anything. If so, you'll probably need to rethink how you are using that container.

Comment: I would guess that the `centeringContainer` is the container to the inputs, and it's falling below *other* invisible elements due to the negative `z-index` (which seems a bit strange with what we're given). I agree that there's not enough information to say though, and your guess also makes sense.

Comment: @DwightB Great! Glad we could help! And welcome to StackOverflow! Since this answer resolved your issue, would you mind accepting it as the correct answer? Thanks and good luck!